# Show charts and plots in plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-3, plot

I'm creating a plugin to guide a user though a GIS analysis process.  One of the things the user wants is the ability to display "charts" of the resulting data sets.  I'm looking to build simple statistical charts such as, histograms, bar charts, pie charts, etc of the fields in the resulting data set.  The charts to be displayed are not geo-specific so the built in Diagrams are not quite what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for an approach to display plots of the result data set as a layer or a using either a python (matplotlib, ggpot for python) or javascript (d3, vega (vega-lite), plotly, etc) plotting package.

Comment: What about the DataPlotly plugin? https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly#dataplotly